# Labview pop up requesting folder/file

Tags: integration, labview

I just encountered an issue with a Labview project.

**Background**

The software in question is usually a standalone application, but for the sake of debugging purposes we found a way to run it in the Labview environment with the source files.

**Issue**

When we press the run command (which is not broken btw), it starts processing the files I guess, and at some point a folder explorer will pop up without further detail on what it is requesting. We have been trying to select the MAIN folder (where the MAIN.VI is), the SOURCE folder which contains all the VIs and subVIs of the project, but either way it just updates a log tab with the text "The application has stopped"(which I assume is due to us not selecting the correct file/folder).

I guess my main questions are,

- Is there a way to tell what this pop up is expecting us to select?
- Are there known function blocks which could be asking for a file/folder path?

**Additional information***

A couple of months ago, someone knew this path and we have run it correctly, but he just forgot it, so that is why I am certain that it works this way. It runs in a ***Labview 13*** environment.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Greetings.

Answer (score 0):

Try [searching the VI Hierarchy](https://zone.ni.com/reference/en-XX/help/371361N-01/lvhowto/searching_in_the_vi_hierar/) by name for likely culprits:

> 1. Open a VI or project and select **View»VI Hierarchy** to display the VI
>      Hierarchy window.
> 2. Initiate a search by typing the name of the item
>      you want to find anywhere in the window. As you type the text, the
>      search string appears, displaying the text as you type. LabVIEW
>      highlights one item at a time whose name begins with the search
>      string.
> 3. If there is more than one item with a name that begins with
>      the search string, press the `Enter` key to search for the next item
>      that matches the search string. Press the `Shift-Enter` keys to find
>      the previous item that matches the search string.

I'm pretty sure all the LabVIEW primitives that can display a file or folder dialog have either `file` or `folder` in their names but if that doesn't help you could also try `save` or `write`.

If you find more than one result, [set breakpoints](http://www.ni.com/getting-started/labview-basics/tools) on them before running the code. When execution reaches the breakpoint it will halt and highlight the breakpoint position; you can then use the [Step In / Step Over](http://www.ni.com/getting-started/labview-basics/debug#Block%20Diagram%20Toolbar) to check whether that's the node that triggers the dialog (and the Pause button to continue execution if not).